# How to password protect magento cms page.?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to protect my pages (not whole site) with password in magento.

I want to add one password field in magento admin panel at CMS block. So when I create new page, I can also set password for it.

When I hit the URL of a page then it should popup to take password and after inserting proper password then page should be opened.

How can I do this or Is there any extension.?

Comment: want a pop .....?

Comment: http://www.comprepairgurus.com/protect-magento-pages/

Answer (score 3):

[Password Protecting Your Pages with htaccess](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/)

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Page"

<Files "mypage.html">
  Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "myotherpage.html">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```